# show the beginning balance and ending balance based on date selected PHP mysqlquery

Tags: php, mysql

I changed my transaction to one single table. How can I show the beginning balance in and ending balance based on the date selected.

Here's my new Transaction table.

TBL NAME: transaction_history

| trans_itemdesc | trans_qtyin | trans_wtin | trans_datein | trans_qtyout | trans_wtout | trans_dateout | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 500 | 5000 | 2020-11-01 |  |  |  |  |
| Item2 | 300 | 3000 | 2020-11-25 |  |  |  |  |
| Item1 | 200 | 2000 | 2020-11-01 |  |  |  |  |
| Item1 |  |  |  | 50 | 2020-11-11 |  |  |
| Item2 |  |  |  | 25 | 2020-11-31 |  | OPEN |
| Item1 |  |  |  | 40 | 2020-11-31 |  | OPEN |
| Item1 |  |  |  | 100 | 2020-11-04 |  | OPEN |

Desired output as of November

| Product | BegBal | In | Out | EndBal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 0 | 700 | 140 | 560 |
| Item2 | 0 | 300 | 25 | 275 |

Output on the next MOnth

| Product | BegBal | In | Out | EndBal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 560 | 0 | 0 | 660 |
| Item2 | 275 | 0 | 0 | 275 |

The beginning balance should carry the ending balance for the next month.

Comment: with your edits, your sample beginning balances no longer make sense; explain how you are calculating that?

Comment: BegBal is the sum of the EndBal from the Previous month + In of the month.

Comment: Consider storing all transactions in a single table

Comment: @SprakenDude I understand that, but how are you calculating it from your data? where does "800" come from for Item 1 in november, when there are no in or out records from before november?

Comment: @ysth yes no records from before November but theres an In in November which is 800 so 0 from previous month + the IN in november = 800

Comment: @SprakenDude but an 800 in november should show up in the In and EndBal for a november report.  If you want it to show in the BegBal too, there isn't a difference between BegBal and EndBal??

Answer (score 0):

You really should just have one table; separate in and out tables make more problems than they solve.  Guessing at some of your column names, I suspect you don't really have a column named 'Date Out' etc

```
select product as Product,
    coalesce(sum(case when dt < '2020-12-01' then amount end),0) as BegBal,
    coalesce(sum(case when dt between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-31' and type='in' then amount end),0) as In,
    coalesce(sum(case when dt between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-31' and type='out' then -amount end),0) as Out,
    coalesce(sum(case when dt <= '2020-12-31' then amount end),0) as EndBal
from (
    select 'in' as type, product, date_in as dt, in as amount from in
    union all
    select 'out' as type, product, date_out, -amount from out
) in_out;
```

Comment: can u help me with subqueries getting the beg bal, in, out  and ending balance based on date selected. I've already change my Table to a single table.